# Disable overlapping shapes in Visio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visio, overlapping

I drop shapes onto a Visio page/doc into an area depending on their x, y value. Some of the shapes contain similar x and y coordinates and therefore overlap eachother. Is the there a way to automatically prevent shapes from overlapping on the page? Or can an equation be put in place to move shapes a specific amount of inches to ensure they are no longer overlapping? Below is the code I have implemented so far.

```
        var vApp = new Visio.Application();
        Visio.Document vDoc, vStencil;
        Visio.Page vPage;
        Visio.Shape vToShape, vFromShape, vConnector;
        Visio.Master vConnectorMaster, vFlowChartMaster;
        double dblXLocation;
        double dblYLocation;
        Visio.Cell vBeginCell, vEndCell;
        int iCount;
        string TEMPLATEPATH = @"C:\temp\Test\testtemplate.vsdx";

        //Change this constant to match your choice of location and file name.
        string SAVENEWFILE = @"C:\temp\test\testfile.vsdx";

        //open the template without any open parameters
        vDoc = vApp.Documents.Open(TEMPLATEPATH);

        vPage = vApp.ActivePage;
        //now, load a Stencil containing basic flowchart shapes
        vStencil = vApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\test\teststencil.vssx");
        vFlowChartMaster = vStencil.Masters[1];

        for (iCount = 0; iCount < xValues.Length; iCount++)
        {

            vFlowChartMaster = vStencil.Masters[aryValues[0, 0]];
            dblXLocation = getXLocation(xValues[iCount]);
            dblYLocation = getYLocation(yValues[iCount]);
            vToShape = vPage.Drop(vFlowChartMaster,
               dblXLocation, dblYLocation);
            vToShape.Text = names[iCount];
            vToShape.TextStyle.ToLower();



            vFromShape = vToShape;
            vToShape = null;



        }

        vDoc.Pages[1].Name = "Graph";
        try
        {
            //Delete the previous version of the file.
            File.Delete(SAVENEWFILE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }


        vDoc.SaveAs(SAVENEWFILE);
        vDoc.Close();
        vApp.Quit();
        vDoc = null;
        vApp = null;
        GC.Collect();
```

Attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zu4U.jpg) are the first 3 shapes that get dropped onto the graph which overlap. There will be approx 70 more shapes to be plotted spread out over the graph with some overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

At least when droping the shapes manually the following 2 flags help avoiding overlaps.
Try them in the code, it may work.

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowMisc, visLOFlags).FormulaU = "1"
Application.ActiveWindow.Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowShapeLayout, visSLOPlowCode).FormulaU = "2"
```

Comment: Hi @y4cine, as I'm quite new to working with Visio programmatically, could you tell me how to define the following properties you have mentioned above?:
- visSectionObject
- visRowMisc
- visLOFlags
- visRowShapeLayout
- visSLOPlowcode

Would I need to define the above two lines of code for before each shape is dropped?

Comment: It is from a recorded macro. You may need to replace "Application.ActiveWindow.Shape" by the shape object you're targeting - in your case vToShape.

Comment: The CellsSRC syntax that @y4cine is highlighting is just an alternative (to cell names) way of addressing cells, by Section, Row and Column index.  In C# you need to fully qualified enum + they need to be cast to a short.  So an example of the first line would be `vToShape.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowMisc, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visLOFlags].FormulaU = "1"`

Comment: In terms of your original question, unless you have some kind of leader line (the end of which stays put) you'll really be changing the data by moving additional points.  I think this is a question that's wider than Visio in terms of the algorythm you come up with to decide on how the points are arranged.  D3 has some [collision and clustering handling](https://hi.stamen.com/forcing-functions-inside-d3-v4-forces-and-layout-transitions-f3e89ee02d12) which might be useful reading.  Otherwise you have the opportunity to get your initial drop position and then use `Page.SpatialSearch` to adjust.